# Rails Javascript causing CSRF token authenticity error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatable

I have a Rails 4 app. When I added the Jquery Datatables javascript cdn (https://cdn.datatables.net/r/bs/jq-2.1.4,dt-1.10.9/datatables.min.js) to my app, my ajax requests began throwing CSRF errors.

When I remove the line `<%= javascript_include_tag "https://cdn.datatables.net/r/bs/jq-2.1.4,dt-1.10.9/datatables.min.js" %>`, everything works as intended.

Any solutions to this odd behavior? Thanks.